# Matching five characters in Excel/VBA using RegEx, with first character being dependant on cell value

Tags: regex, excel, vba, regular-language

I need your help! I’d like to use RegEx in a Excel/VBA environment. I do have an approach, but I’m kind of reaching my limits...

I need to match 5 characters within a great many lines of string (the string being in column B of my excel sheet, A comes later). The 5 characters can be 5 digits or a „K“ followed by 4 digits (ex. `12345`, `98765`, `K2345`). This would be covered by `(\d{5}|K\d{4})`.

Them five can be preceeded or followed by letters or special characters, but not by numbers. Meaning no leading zeros are allowed and also the digits shouldn’t just be matched within a longer number. That's one point where I'm stuck.

If there’s more than one possible match in a string, I need them all to be matched. If the same number has been matched within a line already, I’d like it not to be matched again. For these two requirements, I do have a sort of solution already, that works as part of the VBA code at the end of this posting: `(\d{5}|K\d{4})(?!.*?\1.*$)`

In addition, I do have a specific single digit (or a „K“) in column A. I need the five characters to start with this specific character, or otherwise not be matched.

Example of strings (numbered). The two columns A and B are separated by "|" for better readability

> (1) | 1 | 2018/ID**11298** 00000012345 PersoNR: 889899 Bridgestone BNPN
>   (2) | 3 | Kompo **32280**EP ###Baukasten### 3789936690 ID PFK Carbon0
>   (3) | 2 | **20613**, **20614**, Mietop Antragsnummer C300Coup IVS 33221 ABF
>   (4) | 2 | Q**21009** China lokal produzierte Derivate f/Radverbund 991222 VV
>   (5) | 6 | ID:**61953** F-Pace Enfantillages (Machine arriere) VvSKPMG Lyon09
>   (6) | 2 | 2017/**22222** 22222 **21895** Einzelkostenprob. **28932** ZürichMP KOS
>   (7) | K | ID:**K1245** Panamera Nitsche Radlager Derivativ Bayreumion PwC
>   (8) | 7 | LaunchSupport QBremsen BBG BFG BBD **70142**,**70119** KK 70142

The results that I'm looking for here are:

> (1) | 11298 | ............................. [but don't match 12345, since no preceeding numbers allowed]
>   (2) | 32280 | ............................. [but don't match 37899 within 3789936690]
>   (3) | 20613 | 20614 | ................ [match both starting with a 2, don't match the one starting with 3]
>   (4) | 21009 | ............................. [preceeded by a letter, which is perfectly fine
>   (5) | 61953 | ..............................[random example]
>   (6) | 22222 | 21895 | 28932 | ... [match them all, but no duplicates]
>   (7) | K1245 | ............................. [special case with a "K"]
>   (8) | 70142 | 70119 | ................ [ignore second 70142]

The RegEx/VBA Code that I've put together so far is:

```
Sub RegEx()

Dim varOut() As Variant
Dim objRegEx As Object
Dim lngColumn As Long
Dim objRegA As Object
Dim varArr As Variant
Dim lngUArr As Long
Dim lngTMP As Long

On Error GoTo Fin

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

varArr = .Range("B2:B50")

Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")

With objRegEx

.Pattern = "(\d{5}|K\d{4})(?!.*?\1.*$)" 'this is where the magic happens
.Global = True

For lngUArr = 1 To UBound(varArr)
Set objRegA = .Execute(varArr(lngUArr, 1))

If objRegA.Count >= lngColumn Then
lngColumn = objRegA.Count
End If

Set objRegA = Nothing
Next lngUArr

If lngColumn = 0 Then Exit Sub
ReDim varOut(1 To UBound(varArr), 1 To lngColumn)
For lngUArr = 1 To UBound(varArr)
Set objRegA = .Execute(varArr(lngUArr, 1))
For lngTMP = 1 To objRegA.Count
varOut(lngUArr, lngTMP) = objRegA(lngTMP - 1)
Next lngTMP
Set objRegA = Nothing
Next lngUArr

End With

.Cells(2, 3).Resize(UBound(varOut), UBound(varOut, 2)) = varOut

End With

Fin:
Set objRegA = Nothing
Set objRegEx = Nothing
If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

This code is checking the string from column B and delivering its matches in columns C, D, E etc. It's not matching duplicates. It is however matching numbers within larger numbers, which is a problem. `\b` for example doesn't work for me, because I still want to match `12345` in `EP12345`.

Also, I have no idea how to implement the character from column A to be the very first character.

I've uploaded my excel file here: [mollmell.de/RegEx.xlsm](http://mollmell.de/RegEx.xlsm)

Thank you so much for suggestions
Stephan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort out the numbers which are too long, you can use a negative lookbehind and lookahead that doesn't match preceding and successing digits:

```
(?x) (?<!\d) (\d{5} | K\d{4}) (?!\d)
```

https://regex101.com/r/RBnoMo/1

To match only numbers with the key in column 2 is rather hard. Maybe you match either the key or the numbers and do the logic afterwards:

```
(?x) 
\|[ ](?<key>.)[ ]\| | 
(?<!\d) (?<number>\d{5} | K\d{4}) (?!\d)
```

https://regex101.com/r/60d0yT/2

Comment: Thanks for your help! While `(?x)(?<!\d)(\d{5}|K\d{4})(?!\d)` works quite good on regex101, it somehow doesn't as part of my VBA code. `.Pattern = "(?x)(?<!\d)(\d{5}|K\d{4})(?!\d)"` just delivers an error. Do you happen to have a solution for that?

Comment: If I just include the lookahead assertion `.Pattern = "(\d{5}|K\d{4})(?!\d)"`, there's somehow no error. When including the lookbehind assertion `(?x)(?<!\d)(\d{5}|K\d{4})(?!\d)` there is an error.

Comment: Ok well I just found out that the VBA adaption of RegEx does not support lookbehind assertions (just lookahead ones)